# Use of puts in a file

Tags: file

So I have some code to compare a string from file to a user input which has been error checked to remove spaces.

```
char text[100];
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
char string[100];

void space(void);

int main(/*int argc,char *argv[]*/)
{
  int count = 1;
  char wd[20], word[20];
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("Student Usernames.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("given file doesn't exist");
    getch();
  } else
  {
    printf("Enter the word to search: ");
    gets(text);
    space();

    fscanf(fp, "%s", wd);
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
      if (strcmp(string, wd) == 0)
      {
        printf("%s found in the file. the given word is the %d word in the file",
                word, count);
        count = 0;
        break;
      } else
      {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", wd);
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count != 0)
    {
      printf("given word is not found in the file");
    }
    getch();
  }
}

void space(void) //Prototype stage, w/o semi colon
{
  while (text[c] != '\0')
  {
    if (!(text[c] == ' ' && text[c] == ' '))
    {
      string[d] = text[c];
      d++;
    }
    c++;
  }
  string[d] = '\0';
  c = 0;
  d = 0;

  getch();
}
```

There is a small problem however, when I go ahead to display the code it will give some random garbage as the word that is in file,
for example: Input: A p p l e. Program turns A p p l e into Apple. Output: %^&$£$%^&

Anyone know what's wrong? 
edit: text added.

Comment: I don't think this code compiles. The variable "text" is used but is never defined.

Comment: `void space(char *);` would be a prototype. `void space(char *text) {` would be the opening of a function. And what is the point of `text[c] == ' ' && text[c] == ' '`?

Comment: `word[20]` is never given a value but yet it is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    printf("%s found in the file. the given word is the %d word in the file", 
                                                                 word, count);
```

In above printf you print `word` which not assigned anyway in your code instead that just print `wd` string.

Answer (score -1):

Hahaha, turns out the output should be string, not word, the problem is SOLVED

Comment: You might want to post the whole solution and then accept your answer in order.